# Touchpad not recognised

Tags: 14.04, boot, drivers, usb, touchpad

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 for the first time. My laptop is a toshiba satellite (PSKT4E-0HM009N5) bought from Denmark.

I can't see my cursor if i don't have a usb computer mouse. When i plug it in everything works fine. How can i use my touchpad? Do i need to install some drivers (The toshiba website doesn't have drivers for this model and all drivers i can see are for windows) ?

If i need to install an other version of Ubuntu, how can i boot from USB (i have already a bootable USB but Function buttons/delete/esc don't work while opening)

Answer (score 0):

Type the command "xinput" into terminal. Is your touchpad listed?
If not, most likely you won't be able to use it.

From what I can tell with the research I did, the L-50 has a Synaptics touchpad. These are normally universally supported by most linux distros- it may simply be a hardware problem.

Comment: I am getting this : 
http://imgur.com/a/6IW7W
I can see it there but i can't use it

Comment: It is also weird being a hardware problem as it was working perfectly since yesterday that i had Windows 10...

Comment: Yeah, your touchpad is detected. It's probably a hardware problem. Try disabling and re-enabling it with "xinput disable/enable <touchpad list #>".

Comment: Still not working

Comment: What should i do if it is a hardware problem?

Comment: Does the touchpad work under Windows? Try booting another OS. If need be, send it back to Toshiba (if its under warranty), or use a mouse.

Comment: Yeah it was working 2 days ago on Windows 10.  I don't think that installing ubuntu can destroy my hardware....

Comment: Seems like a driver issue then. I would reboot into Windows to make sure it didn't just die :p. Do you have a hardware enable/disable Fn key combo? Try that. Try this as well: "sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics". If it exists, remove/purge it and reinstall.

Comment: Yes, i've tried the function button enough times (also checked it in BIOS) i've also run this command and reinstalled it a couple of times but still the problem exists.

Comment: I don't know what to say then. I would retry it under Windows, and, if need be, return it. Good luck, sorry I couldn't help further.

Comment: I re-installed windows and everything works fine...